# ¿Se puede dividir un index.php con forms en varios archivos?

Tags: php, html

Estoy empezando a tocar php (aunque tenía bastante experiencia de programación en C++) y tengo algunas dudas.
El caso es que en el index.php me gustaría poner varios forms pero para que quede limpio, lo que me gustaría es poder llamar a funciones que invocaran a cada form.

Actualmente, para que me funcione tengo el código de la siguiente manera:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Prueba de PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 
 <form id="nomfromnum" action="getCharName.php" method="GET">
    <input type="number" min="1" name="charidbox" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Seleccionar personaje">
</form>

 <form id="despPers" method="POST">
    <select name="nomChar">
    <?php
    
    include("conection.php");
    
    $con=conectar();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Personajes";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row["Character_id"].'">'.$row["Character_name"].'</option>';
      }  
    ?>
    </select><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

El primer formulario si que he conseguido sacarlo a otro archivo (getCharName.php).
Pero para la siguiente función (despPers), que es para crear un menu desplegable e inicializar los elementos que tendrá, no encuentro la manera de poder mover esto a un archivo externo.
He intentado cambiar el encabezado por `<form id="despPers"  action="despPers.php" method="POST">` y crear un archivo despPers.php con el siguiente código pero ha sido infructuoso.

```
    <select name="nomChar">
 <?php
 
    function despChar($conexion){
    
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Personajes";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row["Character_id"].'">'.$row["Character_name"].'</option>';
      }  
    }
    
    include("conection.php");
    
    $con=conectar();
    
    despChar($con);
    $con->close(); 
    
 ?>
    </select><br>
```

Evidentemente, no ha funcionado.
Así que en eso estoy.
¿Alguien me puede indicar cómo puedo hacer esto?
La verdad es que puede que sea algo básico, pero estoy muy verde en php y html en general.
¡Muchas grácias!

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo que yo puedo ver es que solo te falta un submit para el segundo formulario y claro agregar el action que es hacia donde se hará el POST del formulario, puedes agregar todos los formulario que quieras mientras estos estén direccionados a distintos archivos no tendrás problemas.

```php
<html>
<head>
  <title>Prueba de PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 
<form id="nomfromnum" action="getCharName.php" method="GET">
    <input type="number" min="1" name="charidbox" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Seleccionar personaje">
</form>

<form id="despPers"  action="despPers.php" method="POST">
    <select name="nomChar">
<?php
include("conection.php");
$con=conectar();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Personajes";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row["Character_id"].'">'.$row["Character_name"].'</option>';
  }  
?>
    </select><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Seleccionar producto">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero no ha funcionado como quería.
He intentado usando este código:
```
 <form id="despPers" action="despChar.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
```
Y dentro de despChar.php he movido lo que tenía anteriormente

Pero entonces el en index me aparece simplemente un botón y cuando le doy ya me lleva al desplegable (sin rellenar).

Answer (score 0):

Vaya, al final era todo un nombre de variables mal puestas. Bueno, de todas maneras esto es lo que he hecho.
En index.php he puesto

```
<form id="despPers" action="despChar.php" method="POST">
    <select name="nomChar">
    <?php    
    include("despChar.php");    
    despChar();    
    ?>
    </select><br>
</form>
```

Y en despChar.php

```
 <?php 
    function despChar(){ 
    
        include("conection.php");    
        echo '<option value="0">Character</option>';
        $con=conectar(); 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Personajes";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo '<option value="'.$row["Character_id"].'">'.$row["Character_name"].'</option>';
        }  
     
        $con->close();    
    } 
 ?>
```